# Postback collapsing fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a login button with he following code.

```
protected void prv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            string postbackUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http", "https");
            Response.Redirect(postbackUrl);

        }
    }

    login_box.Visible = true;
}
```

The problem is, if the user is browsing using http and clicks on login link which fires off the prv_Click, the site redirects you to https which is correct, but the login_box which is standard div set to visible false and run at server never gets set to true. The user has to click on the login link again which then expands it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the visibility on the button click, set it on page load.  Something like this should work:

```
login_box.Visible = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection;
```

Note that it shouldn't be in an `IsPostBack`.  This will always ensure that it's only visible when you have a secure connection.  If it needs to be hidden for any other reasons, then you'll need to modify the expression accordingly.

Comment: I htink you're right Servy, think needs to be on Page_Load with further conditions